# Looking for a OSGi capable dependency-injection-framework with support for session scoped services

Tags: java, spring, cdi, blueprint-osgi, eclipse-gemini

This question is a followup question to [Spring framework download as OSGi bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267343).

I am looking for a framework that is capable of doing the following:

- it has to work in an OSGi environment
- some concept of beans/services/whatever you want to call it
- this beans/services need to be able to have a session scope, ideally tied to a web session
- injection of this beans/services into the components that need them via dependency injection (optional but highly appreciated - and I guess a framework that can do the stuff from above most likely can also do dependency injection)
- must be considered reliable and stable, with good outlook on future support

Originally I was looking into Eclipse Gemini Blueprint, but (a) I have troubles to get it up and running (refer to question above) and (b) not only an answer to my question showed some concerns but also I am not so sure about using it anymore myself. I can't find much references that it is widely used, the forum is almost dead (like 8 pages in 4 years) and it seems there are not many contributors on git involved (23 commits for whole 2013). I don't want to end up with a framework thats considered abandonware in less than a year.

My question now is: Is there any framework around (besides Eclipse Gemini) that is capable of session-scoped beans and preferrably dependency injection? I also accept a "no" as an answer as I start to fear that there is really none out there. Alternatively you can talk me back into using Eclipse Gemini if you have good arguments.

Comment: You have "spring" in your tags; does that mean you will only accept Spring as a framework? O/w look at JBoss application server. While it is quite heavy duty, it also manages conversation and session scopes just fine.

Comment: In general I'm open to all frameworks, as long as they work withing an OSGi container (or can be used as OGSi container). I put spring in the tags as Eclipse Gemini Blueprint originates from Spring Dynamic Modules. Of course, the smaller the framework, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Pax CDI](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI).

Don't be put off by the current version, it's maturing fast and is pretty stable. A colleague of mine uses it for his pet project and he seems to be quite happy with it.

Comment: All in all Pax CDI lives of one single developer (https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.cdi/graphs/contributors). I don't think thats what my customers are considering as safe for the future :(

Comment: How many copies of yourself do you offer to your customers to feel safe?

Comment: Usually five, one for every workday in a week, how do you handle that? The framework I am looking for will be part of a basic software architecture for a software that will be in use for most likely 10 to 15 years plus. A library that is not maintained anymore bears a security risk our customers won't take. Of course noone knows what the future brings but using a library that looks almost-dead right from the start is just not an option. Hey, I would be happy too if i just could use everything I want, but then I would not need to post this question.